# UITileLayer display Ignoring bogus layer size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

Can any one please tell me whats this warning about? the UTextView became empty, i need to scroll to show my content every time i have this warning

```
[<_UITileLayer: 0x1464c5e0> display]: Ignoring bogus layer size (665719930880.000000, 549755813888.000000), contentsScale 2.000000, backing store size (1331439861760.000000, 1099511627776.000000)
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same behaviour. did you ever find out what was wrong?

Comment: i have this bug when i try to create a widget from UITextView, so to resolve this bug i  use extention to add a new traitement to my UiTextView. but i can't get what is the problem

Comment: issam - can you please explain how you resolved with with your UITextView?

Answer (score 1):

I just got the same warning when using the textView in the nib , and i google a method to fix this base on [original link](http://www.wangyan.im/2016/01/30/solution-of-error-uitextview-ignoring-bogus-layer-size/),it seems works for the warning

self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false